# Angular2 app in iFrame

Tags: angular, iframe

This might be a simple question.  I have angular2 app and then a couple of customers are asking for it to be in an iFrame.  I did a couple of searches but all I found is iFrames in angular2, not exactly what I am looking.

I haven't done much with iFrames, but I have some thoughts but figured I would get some feedback before deep diving and losing hours in an impossibility.

Comment: provide the link of the app in i frame it will load as usual

Comment: my web guy was saying it didn't work.  Thanks, I'm going to try.  I know our app is large so we might have some other issues.  But thanks didn't think it was that simple.